# Android Firebase onDataChange is not called?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have more than 40,000 nodes in my Firebase Database. But whenever I am trying to read a key from my Android code, the `onDataChange` method is not getting called.

**MyCode:**

```
 Firebase firebase = new Firebase(my url);
            firebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange : " + dataSnapshot);

                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {

                        Map map = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                        Iterator accountIterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
                        while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {

                            Map.Entry accountPair = (Map.Entry) accountIterator.next();

                            Log.d(TAG, "accountPair : Key : " + accountPair.getKey() + " , Value : " + accountPair.getValue());
                        }

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled : " + firebaseError);
                }
            });
```

[I want to retrieve Student node details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDrb2.png)

Please let me know. I am not able to find any issue in the code. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#value_events

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/database/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/database/PostDetailActivity.java

Comment: **Your database ref seems wrong.** Moreover valueEventListener is called when the value of your reference key changes. But I don't see any such ref.  Please update that part of question if it's just an error.

Comment: @NishantDubey No the ref is perfect , i checked out the reference url , it's working fine in the browser , so what's wrong in the code? please help

Comment: Which version of firebase are you using ?

Comment: Did you check your logcat to see if `onCancelled()` is getting called. Because that is the most likely problem. Aside from that it is hard to say what's wrong with this code. It is more likely that another part of the app is causing the problem. Show the URL (hiding it is not making your app more secure), show the data at that location (as JSON text, no screenshot), show your security rules (as JSON text, no screenshot), etc.

Comment: can you show us you us java class and firebase database screen shot ?

Comment: @NishantDubey compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is to check you have correct permissions to read from your database. Go to 
https://console.firebase.google.com/project/[your_database_url]/database/rules and check . Not ideal in prod, but for testing you can set read to true

```
  {
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": "auth != null"
   }
  }
```

Next gotcha is to remember that the listeners are asynchronous  fire and forget calls. So any manipulations to the data should be done once the data has been received in the onDataChange() method.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firebase link -> Database -> Rules -> Probably values here are false in your case. Make it true as the following.

```
  {
    "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
```