# Firebase onDataChange method is not called even if the data is changed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code is as shown below:

```
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    private static final String TAG = "OrderManagementFragment";


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_managment, container, false);

        //get reference to the orders node
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("orders");

        // app_title change listener
        mFirebaseInstance.getReference("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9b").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

My credentials for firebase is as shown below:

[image: firebase schema]

Now, what happens here is , whenever data is changed from backend side , onDatachange method never gets called.So is there anything missing in this method?

**I am testing this via android emulator, so is it the problem ?**

Comment: You attach your listener to the wrong location. Change it to        `mFirebaseDatabase.child("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9b").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`.

Comment: see the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53433940/1308990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change your code, u dont need reference inconstructor becouse aplication method will know what u need.

Data is not changed becouse u no have static like textView on your layout. When you got a Toast, its start once so u cant see that its changed

```
 //get reference to the orders node
            mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference();

            // app_title change listener
            mFirebaseInstance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataSnapshot.child("YOUR REFERENCE HERE")getValue(String.class), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
```

I give you example from my application:

```
 mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        settingsText2.setText("Loading...");
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                settingsTextWithScrollView.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube1").child("Text").getValue(String.class));
                settingsText2.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube1").child("Information").getValue(String.class));
                settingsTextWithScrollView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openYoutubeIntent(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube1").child("Link").getValue(String.class));
                    }
                });
                settingsText3.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube2").child("Text").getValue(String.class));
                settingsText4.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube2").child("Information").getValue(String.class));
                settingsText3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openYoutubeIntent(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube2").child("Link").getValue(String.class));
                    }
                });
                settingsText5.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube3").child("Text").getValue(String.class));
                settingsText6.setText(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube3").child("Information").getValue(String.class));
                settingsText5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        openYoutubeIntent(dataSnapshot.child("Youtube3").child("Link").getValue(String.class));
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot.child("orders").child("58ca237b2e2c211dc0c7ed9b").child("order_status").getValue(String.class))      gives me null value for my schema

Comment: remove this: .child("order_stat‌​us")

Answer (score 0):

its a static call like this

```
FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DataBaseRefrence dbRef=database.getRefrence("nodeOfData");
DataSnapshot ds=dbRef.getChildren("gettingWhatIsInNodeOfData"); or 
better yet chain them DataSnapshot 
ds=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getRefrence("orders").getChildren();
```

Comment: You also have concurrency issues if you set some variable equal to a database value and then try and do something with it