# Check if value exists using firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I just want my code to check if value already exist in database when i click my button but somehow it doesn't return any value. I think i already follow tutorial on internet but not sure why it doesn't work for me.

This how my database looks like:
[image]

And this my onclick method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        Intent intent;

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.textViewLoginHere:
                intent = new Intent(ActivityRegister.this, ActivityLogin.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.buttonRegister:
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                checkIfUsernameExists();
                break;

        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is my method to check if value exists:

```
public void checkIfUsernameExists(){
        username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference usernameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usernames");
        usernameRef.orderByValue().equalTo(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                enableButton();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code and how i can fix it? Thank you in advance

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very clear. Does `onDataChange` get called? If so, which of the toasts is shown?    And as a general observation: don't ignore `onCancelled`: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Answer (score 0):

try this ..

```
 public void checkIfUsernameExists(){
        username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        DatabaseReference usernameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usernames");
        usernameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String user = (String) data.getValue();

                    if (user.equals(username)) {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        enableButton();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

in the example here you will got the "usernames" reference

```
 DatabaseReference usernameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("usernames");
```

on the response `onDataChange()` we will get dataSnapshot object that retrieve all the data about this reference

then we will make a loop for all the children in the `dataSnapshot` that we received

the children in the example is :

- FMt7S4ybHcf2f....oT2
- ioRdDue ...... sE22

then we get the Value in the child by  `data.getValue()`

and check if the value in this child equal to username

Comment: You should give the OP some explanations, about what was wrong in his code and why your code will work.

Comment: i am not sure if this will work i wait for him response :)

Comment: Is this answer based on an assumption? What was wrong in OP's code? You should help him understand where he did wrong, not only write him this  code.

Comment: updated .. why you ask for explain if you copied the code !!

Comment: I provided my own one, with my own explanations. I'm asking you to explain so the OP can have better understaning.

Comment: your own !!? just changed `data` to `ds`  and says my own , you must monitored in your answer that you used the previous example with another explanations any way have a good day man i don't look for point but don't make this community looking bad .. help developer with your own solution not to copy solution for others.

Comment: The code in my answer is the code mostly provided by the op. The same as you have. If there is only a solution it doesn't mean I have copied from you. But it's OP's call to choose which answer helps him the most.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `dataSnapshot.exists()` it means that you are checking for existens a node, which is an object. You are not checking the existens of a value, which in this case is a String. So in order to see if a value does exists within an object you need to iterate through the childrens of that object. 
So please use the follwing code:

```
public void checkIfUsernameExists(){
    username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    DatabaseReference usernameRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usernames");
    usernameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String user = ds.getValue(String.class);

                if (user.equals(username)) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    enableButton();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, "not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

As you can probably see, I have used `getChildren()` method to iterate through the `DataSnapshot` object to actually get all those childrens. Having those children, we can get the value to see if one of them is equals with the one we are looking for. In case of equality, we Toast `exists`, otherwise, `not exists`.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake the root cause is because of the rules. This is a register page so the user is still not authorized. I just change it to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

then i manage to read the data. For more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851052/android-firebase-ondatachange-is-not-called). Just to add my original code works fine. after that. Very funny!

Anyway thanks for all that is trying to help. Thank you.

Comment: that's wasn't the question , but if you ask about this rules `By default, your database rules require Firebase Authentication and grant full read and write permissions only to authenticated users. The default rules ensure your database isn't accessible by just anyone before you get a chance to configure it. Once you're set up, you can customize your rules to your needs. Here are some common examples`

Comment: `The default rules require Authentication. They allow full read and write access to authenticated users of your app. They are useful if you want data open to all users of your app but don't want it open to the world.`